# Bounds for the error of this approximation to the Bessel function

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximation, bessel-functions

I found a nice explicit approximation to the Bessel function today, using the integral:

$$J_0(x)=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{\cos x u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du$$

With [Chebyshev-Gauss quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%E2%80%93Gauss_quadrature) we can see that the following approximation works:

$$J_0(x) \approx \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \cos \left(x \cos \left( \frac{2k-1}{2n} \pi \right) \right)$$

Here's an example for $n=20$, which shows that the approximation is very good for small $x$.

[image]

---

However, for large arguments the quadrature quickly loses the accuracy, because of strong oscillatory behavior of the integrand.

Numerically for $ x \gg n$ the error quickly blows up and starts oscillating.

> Because I want to implement this approximation in an algorithm, I would like to know if we can derive explicit bounds for the error:

$$E(n,x)=J_0(x)- \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \cos \left(x \cos \left( \frac{2k-1}{2n} \pi \right) \right)$$

Comment: One more interesting question from you ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, thank you! Your expertise is always appreciated. I never had a numerical methods course, so I learn them as I go along. As for this, I already found the explicit expression for the remainder term, so I will probably answer the question myself